# Lazy evaluation of modules with Webpack

Tags: webpack, lazy-evaluation

My understanding is that Webpack's optimizations works best when the modules are defined using the ESM module format, that way it can statically know what's imported and exported from a modules and can better execute `concatenateModules`,  among others optimizations.

In order to achieve that we don't want Babel to compile our modules down to `commonjs` or other formats, so I'm using  `{ modules: false }` as a config on "preset-env".

That being said, `@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs` has a `lazy` option to make evaluating dependencies lazily, which is something I want to enable, but that will also transpile everything down to `commonjs`.

See more at https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-modules-commonjs#lazy

Does Webpack support this sort of `lazy evaluation` behavior? How can I enable that?

Here is an example of what of what I mean by `lazy evaluation`:

The default way of evaluating module dependencies is `eager`, they will be evaluated right before anything happens inside the module. Ex:

```js
import _ from 'lodash';

export function toUpperCase(str) {
  return _.toUpper(str);
}
```

When transpiled down to `eager evaluated` (default) `commonjs` roughly becomes:

```js
const _ = require('lodash').default;

module.exports.toUpperCase = function(str) {
  return _.toUpper(str);
};
```

But with `lazy evaluation` it would become:

```js
module.exports.toUpperCase = function(str) {
  return require('lodash').default.toUpper(str);
};
```

This would allow the `lodash` module to only be evaluated when it's actually used, so only when `toUpperCase` is called.

Comment: Take a look at my solution, clicking on the button loads background.js [importlazy](https://github.com/tomik23/importlazy)

Comment: I guess "lazy require" is confusing, I'll change the question to "lazy evaluation" to be more more clear on what I mean.
I'm not looking for lazy imports, I'm looking for a solution to lazy evaluation of a module, where the module is already available, but we only execute it when necessary instead of executing when the `import` is present (eager vs lazy).

Comment: And this is the script that I gave you [importLazy](https://tomik23.github.io/importlazy/) that's what it does. See devTools, `main.[hash].js` is loaded. If I click on the button, the chunk `background.[hash].js` is loaded, so it is loaded when it is needed, that's probably what it was about?

Comment: Thank you for your help!
I'm not asking for a lazy loading, Webpack sort of provides that out of the box already, I'm asking for lazy evaluation, these are 2 different concepts.
I hope the examples I added on the question clarify what I mean.

Comment: Hi @fabiomcosta, I am trying to do the same thing. Just wondering if you have found a solution for this?